# How to get android device version - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to get the Android device version (For example 11, 12). I have been trying to get only the number

This is what I have done till now

```
  void checkVersion(){
    print(Platform.operatingSystemVersion); // it prints "sdk_gphone64_arm64-userdebug 12 S2B2.211203.006 8015633 dev-keys"

   // I'm able to fetch the version number by splitting the string 
   // but the problem is that format of above string will vary by
   // operating system, so not suitable for parsing 

   int platformVersion = int.parse(Platform.operatingSystemVersion.split(' ')[1]); it prints '12'
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) to get any device information you need.

```
Future<String?> getAndroidVersion() async {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    return androidInfo.version.release;
  }
  throw UnsupportedError("Platform is not Android");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`device_info_plus`](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) plugin and get Android, iOS, macOS, Linux versions with the following snippet:

```dart
  Future<String> _getOsVersion() async {
    final deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final info = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
      return info.version.release ?? 'Unknown';
    }
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      final info = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
      return info.systemVersion ?? 'Unknown';
    }
    if (Platform.isMacOS) {
      final info = await deviceInfo.macOsInfo;
      return info.osRelease;
    }
    if (Platform.isLinux) {
      final info = await deviceInfo.linuxInfo;
      return info.version ?? 'Unknown';
    }
    return 'Unknown Version';
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) package to get the device version:

```
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
final androidInfo = await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo;
return androidInfo.version.sdkInt;
```

Or if you don't want to use any external plugin, you can use `Platform.operatingSystemVersion`. But it'll give you:
`"sdk_gphone64_arm64-userdebug 12 S2B2.211203.006 8015633 dev-keys"`

So what you did is right. You've to split the string and get the device version:

```
final systemVerion = Platform.operatingSystemVersion;
int deviceVersion = int.parse(operatingSystemVersion.split(' ')[1]); 
print(deviceVersion);
//prints '12'
```

Comment: **Note**: although parsing it may returns the version number, this string may vary and [according to Flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform/operatingSystemVersion.html) it "is not suitable for parsing".